# Mysql 30+ joins with very small table?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I need to display ads blocks into website based on 30 different criteria (e.g.: user's country, referral url, day of week, ...). Table size is very small, not more than 400 records, but many null values. In more than half cases/records no criteria will be applied and ad will be displayed to all visitors, but in half cases conditions will be applied.

I have 2 options.

Option 1 - 1 table with many null values:

`Table block`

```
block_id | html_to_show | status | views | country_code | if_referral_url | day_of_week | ...
```

SQL

```
SELECT * FROM block WHERE (country_code=$country OR country_code IS NULL) AND (if_referral_url = $url OR if_referral_url IS NULL) AND ...
```

Option 2 - 2 tables with 30+ joins:

`Table block`

```
block_id | html_to_show | status | views
```

`Table conditions`

```
block_id | cond_name | cond_value
1        | country_code | US
1        | if_referral_url | %google%
1        | from_date | 1489143997
...
```

SQL

```
SELECT * FROM block
LEFT JOIN conditions from_date ON from_date.block_id=block.block_id
LEFT JOIN conditions if_referral ON if_referral.block_id=block.block_id
LEFT JOIN conditions country ON country.block_id=block.block_id
...20 more joins here
WHERE from_date.from_date IS NULL OR from_date.from_date>$fromDate
AND if_referral.if_referral IS NULL OR if_referral.if_referral=$ref
AND country.country_code IS NULL OR country.country_code=$country
....
```

Normally the answer would be probably to use joins when there are so many null values. But what in case if there are only 400 records and large number of required joins (30+)? In such small table probably it won't matter if there are null values, but in other hand 30+ joins could make some negative performance affect I guess. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a test which showed without doubt that I should not use joins in this case. I created a simple php script that gets results from db. I used apache ab (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html), 1000 requests. With join it was almost 1000% slower.

For test without joins I used single table test (all fields are varchar 50 except field banner_id)

`banner_id | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 | field5 | field6 | field7 | field8 | field9 | field10`

For joins I used 2 tables. Table test2 with index for banner_id

`banner_id | field | value`

and table test3 with index banner_id

`banner_id | eee`

I also added foreign key (banner_id).

This is my script that inserted data to db:

```
for($n=0;$n<1000;$n++){
  $length = 10;
  $rand = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil($length/strlen($x)) )),1,$length);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO test
          (banner_id,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,field9,field10)
          VALUES ($n,'2".$n.$rand."','3".$n.$rand."','4".$n.$rand."',5".$n.",
          6".$n.",".time().",8".$n.",9".$n.",10".$n.")";
  $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
  $statement->execute();
  $sql = "INSERT INTO test2 (banner_id,field,value)
          VALUES ($n,'field2','2".$n.$rand."'),
                  ($n,'field3','3".$n.$rand."'),
                  ($n,'field4','4".$n.$rand."'),
                  ($n,'field5',5".$n."),
                  ($n,'field6',6".$n."),
                  ($n,'field7',".time()."),
                  ($n,'field8',8".$n."),
                  ($n,'field9',9".$n."),
                  ($n,'field10',10".$n.")";
  $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
  $statement->execute();
  $sql = "INSERT INTO test3 (banner_id,eee)
          VALUES ($n,'".$n.$rand."')";
  $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
  $statement->execute();                    
}
```

This is sql without joins:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE
        (field2 IS NULL OR field2>5)
        AND (field3 IS NULL OR field3>5)
        AND (field4 IS NULL OR field4>5)
        AND (field5 IS NULL OR (field5>10 AND field5<".rand(200,3300)."))
        AND (field6 IS NULL OR (field6>10 AND field6<".rand(200,3300)."))
        AND (field7 IS NULL OR (field7>10 AND field7<".rand(1489408024,1499408024)."))
        AND (field8 IS NULL OR (field8>10 AND field8<".rand(200,3300)."))
        AND (field9 IS NULL OR (field9>10 AND field9<".rand(200,3300)."))
        AND (field10 IS NULL OR (field10>10 AND field10<1100))
        ";
```

And this with joins:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test3
LEFT JOIN test2 cond2 ON cond2.banner_id = test3.banner_id AND cond2.field='field2'
LEFT JOIN test2 cond3 ON cond3.banner_id = test3.banner_id AND cond3.field='field3'
LEFT JOIN test2 cond4 ON cond4.banner_id = test3.banner_id AND cond4.field='field4'
LEFT JOIN test2 cond5 ON cond5.banner_id = test3.banner_id AND cond5.field='field5'
LEFT JOIN test2 cond6 ON cond6.banner_id = test3.banner_id AND cond6.field='field6'
LEFT JOIN test2 cond7 ON cond7.banner_id = test3.banner_id AND cond7.field='field7'
LEFT JOIN test2 cond8 ON cond8.banner_id = test3.banner_id AND cond8.field='field8'
LEFT JOIN test2 cond9 ON cond9.banner_id = test3.banner_id AND cond9.field='field9'
LEFT JOIN test2 cond10 ON cond10.banner_id = test3.banner_id AND cond10.field='field10'
WHERE (cond2.value IS NULL OR cond2.value>5)
  AND (cond3.value IS NULL OR cond3.value>5)
  AND (cond4.value IS NULL OR cond4.value>5)
  AND (cond5.value IS NULL OR (cond5.value>10 AND cond5.value<".rand(200,3300).")) 
  AND (cond6.value IS NULL OR (cond6.value>10 AND cond6.value<".rand(200,3300).")) 
  AND (cond7.value IS NULL OR (cond7.value>10 AND cond7.value<".rand(1489408024,1499408024).")) 
  AND (cond8.value IS NULL OR (cond8.value>10 AND cond8.value<".rand(200,3300)."))  
  AND (cond9.value IS NULL OR (cond9.value>10 AND cond9.value<".rand(200,3300).")) 
  AND (cond10.value IS NULL OR (cond10.value>10 AND cond10.value<1100))
  GROUP BY test3.banner_id";
```

This test showed that it is obviously I should not use normalization structure but only 1 table.